# Check if user belongs to specific group before counting towards usage quota

Tags: azure-api-management

I want to create a policy where our employees can call an API without counting toward any quota. Our employees belong to one specific group in the API Management solution. I want all other users not in that group to count towards a usage quota for their subscription.

My issue is that I cannot figure out how to check if a user is in a specific group in a `when` condition, [because the group list on the user object is a list of objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ref-context-user).

It seems straightforward when it is a map (e.g. headers), or just an array of strings:

```
<!-- for maps, but it is not a map -->
<when condition="@(context.User.Groups.ContainsKey("myGroup"))" />

<!-- for arrays if you know all properties --> 
<when condition="@(context.User.Groups.Contains("myGroup"))" />
```

How can I create a policy like this when I only have the name of the group, not its Id?

```
<when condition="@(!context.User.isInGroup("myGroup")">
    <quota calls="10000" bandwidth="40000" renewal-period="3600" />
</when>
```

Or, phrased another way;

How can I find out if a list of objects contains an object with a specific value for a property? [Kind of like find in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Linq Any method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0) to get true or false, depends if given name exists or not.

To check if `User` is in the given group:

```
<when condition="@(context.User.Groups.Any(x => x.Name == "myGroup"))">
```

If you want to be super secure check also if `User` object exists (it can be null if you call API with "Built-in all-access subscription"):

```
<when condition="@(context.User != null && context.User.Groups.Any(x => x.Name == "myGroup"))">
```

And to revert above condition and check if `User` is not in given group:

```
<when condition="@(context.User == null || !context.User.Groups.Any(x => x.Name == "myGroup"))">
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot! I saw that the Groups property was implementing IEnumerable, but I couldn't figure out what methods were available on that interface.